# MFC How to enable docking for a status bar?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, statusbar, docking

I created the status bar `CStatusBar statusBar;` in the `class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd` class 
and I am doing that:

```
if (!statusBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE, WS_CHILD | CBRS_TOP | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_GRIPPER) ||
    !statusBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR))
{
  return -1;
}

if (!statusBar.CreateEx(this, SBARS_TOOLTIPS, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_BOTTOM | CBRS_GRIPPER))
{
  return -1;
}
statusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT));
```

// and then trying:

```
  statusBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_BOTTOM); // here I recieve an assertion

  EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_BOTTOM);
  DockControlBar(&statusBar);
```

What is the wrong here (Almost the same behaviour works for tool bar)? 
And Is it possible to make a status bar with enabled docking ?

I beelieve it is possible cause I have this in the picture:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEw2r.png)

**UPD**

It is what I have in the code :

```
    if (!m_wndStatusBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_BOTTOM | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC))
    {
        TRACE0("Не удалось создать строку состояния\n");
        return -1;
    }
    m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators) / sizeof(UINT));

    // TODO: 
  m_wndStatusBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
  EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
  DockControlBar(&m_wndStatusBar);
```

And I still recieve an assertion that are becomes only when I add `DockControlBar(&m_wndStatusBar);`. 
without this is don't work too, and I think it is normal 
but why it is don't work with it?

[image]

Comment: Wow is that a bad edit. You just changed your question 100%. Instead, *ask a new question!*. Rolling back to previous edit.

Comment: I wonder to make a new question. But blocked for it (:.

Comment: Also I found a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896341/can-constructor-call-another-constructor-in-c
Thank's for rolling back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statusBar is created twice.  Second time without any resource. Remove the second CreateEx, it should work without any problem.