# How to forward overloaded constructor call to another constructor in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, delegating-constructor

I know that there is no way to do this in [pure C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor), but I was wondering if it is possible to call a constructor from another constructor's initialization list in C++/CLI, same way one can do it in C#.

Example:

```
ref class Foo {
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int i) : Foo() {}
}
```

Comment: C++0x will support this, actually

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is called a "delegating constructor".  It is not available in the language yet.  But there's a formal proposal, you'll find it in annex F.3.1 of the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm).  Given Microsoft's stance towards C++/CLI, that is unlikely to see the light of day anytime soon.

---

UPDATE: delegating constructors did have a life beyond the proposal in that annex, they were added to the standard C++11 language specification.  Microsoft has been working on getting the C++11 additions implemented.  Delegating constructors finally made it for VS2013.  And they also work in C++/CLI in that edition.

Answer (score 3):

You can do following

```
ref class A
{
public:
    A(int p) : p(p) { this->A::A(); }
    A() : p(1) {}

    int p;
};
```

It is not valid C++ code , but VC compiles it fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled by, for the same question. In my case I'm using VS2010.

It is clear that VS2010 will never get updated to fully implement C++11, use VS2015 if you need better compliance with the standard (which I do when I can). But for some (legacy) projects I still have to use VS2010.

An approach that works in many cases (for me) is the use of a private function with all shared initialisation code in it. Example:

```
class A
{
private:
    void Inidialise() { /* common initialisation here */ }

public:
    A()       { Initialise(); /* specific initialisation for A() here */ }
    A(bool a) { Initialise(); /* specific initialisation for A(bool) here */ }
    A(int b)  { Initialise(); /* specific initialisation for A(int) here */ }

    /* etcetera */

}
```

It does not solve all 'problems' and it does not prevent all cases of duplicate code but it goes a long way.

Answer (score -4):

When you said ***"I know that there is no way to do this in pure C++"*** you were in error. It is possible to do that in native C++. You can use the placement new operator to do so.

```
class A 
{ 

public:

   A(int p) : p(p) 
   { new(this)A(); }

   A() : p(1) {}      

   int p; 
};
```