# Refering within the class to constructor with the this pointer

Tags: constructor, c++-cli, this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
ref class station{
public:
    station(){
    };
    void wrapper_1()
    {
        this->somefunct(); /*happy*/
    };
    void wrapper_2()
    {
        this->station(); /*not happy*/
    };
    void somefunct(){
        System::Console::WriteLine(L"abcde");
    };
};

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    station^ temp_1 = gcnew station();
    temp_1->wrapper_1();
    System::Console::ReadLine();
};
```

I want to use the **this** pointer to call my constructor within my *station* class, it doesn't like this and throws the following error:

> error C2273: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->'
>   operator.

Can someone explain to me how the constructor differs to other functions when using the pointer **this** to point to the function. I don't want to take the easy way out using `station::station();`

example of what I meant to @hans-passant

```
#include "stdafx.h"
ref class station{
public:
    station(int par_1,int par_2)
    {
        int sum = par_1 + par_2;
        System::Console::WriteLine(System::Convert::ToString(sum));
//default value output 13
    };
    station(){
        int pass_1 = 5;
        int pass_2 = 8;
        station(pass_1,pass_2); /* But why couldn't I use this->station(pass_1,pass_2);*/
    };
};
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    station^ obj = gcnew station();
    System::Console::ReadLine();
};
```

Comment: You cannot directly call the constructor, trying to do so is meaningless.  The gcnew operator calls it.  Which supplies the essential other essential ingredient, a pointer to the object storage that needs to be initialized by the constructor.  The CLR does not offer a way to break this rule.

Comment: @hans-passant unless I have an overloaded constructor so one constructor is parameterless and sets a default values to pass on to my main constructor because managed constructors parameters cannot contain have default values. And I wanted default values for my constructor parameters.

Comment: I supposed you are talking about "delegating constructors".  Proposed as a future extension of C++/CLI in section F.3.1 of the language specification.  C++11 implemented it for native C++.  You couldn't come up with a worse example btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forward overloaded constructor call to another constructor in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357076/how-to-forward-overloaded-constructor-call-to-another-constructor-in-c-cli/2357752#2357752).

Comment: @hans-passant edit above is what I tried to describe.