# is it proper to have a construction function?

Tags: c++

My class has many constructors and it has a lot to do in the constructor so I was thinking of making a private construct() function to promote code reuse. Is this a good idea? Because I see many libraries that do not do this and have code duplication.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful when calling virtual functions from the constructor, though. It might not behave as you would expect; the version called will be the one that belongs to the class whose constructor is currently being invoked, not the one belonging to what's actually being created.

Comment: What is the reason that you have many constructors? What are the differences between the constructors?

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach They are very small, things like a string, just things to add convenience

Comment: @Toolbox yea I'm aware of that, thanks though :)

Comment: well concrete examples would help us help you, but from what you say I think that most of it can be handled by default arguments, formal argument types that do relevant conversions, and/or the Named Parameters Idiom (see the FAQ). NPI in short is to pass a general options object with chainable setters, one setter per options, like `MyFileClass f( FileOptions().name( "blah" ).locked( false ).createIfNeeded( true ) );` Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally fine and is probably a good idea. What might be concerning is having so many constructors. But it's impossible to say.

Comment: Just make sure it's not a virtual function, unless you're into auto-sodomy that is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308276/50079), which addresses the issue in a general way.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `construct` isn't virtual, it's generally safe. I tend to prefer going the other direction though.

Make as few general constructors as possible, and if I need a lot of easier-to-use convenience construction functions, I use free (non-member) functions, which call the constructor, filling in the missing parameters with suitable default values, and then return the constructed object.

That way I avoid the somewhat iffy issue of constructors calling member functions of the not-yet-constructed object, and I avoid duplicating code in the class.

Comment: If the convenience functions are static members, they can also access the guts of the object and do initialization beyond what the constructor allows.

Comment: Yes, but what's the point? If you need to do *more* than what the constructor allows, I'd say it reeks of bad design. And why drag more code into the class? I prefer manageable classes that focus on one responsibility. And 14 different convenience functions for instantiating the class typically water down that responsibility, and add *a lot* of clutter if they're defined in the class.