# Constructor doesn't set member variable

Tags: c++, class, constructor

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    int bar;

    Foo()
    {
        bar = 1;
        cout << "Foo() called" << endl;
    }

    Foo(int b)
    {
        bar = 0;
        Foo();
        bar += b;
        cout << "Foo(int) called" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(5);
    cout << "foo.bar is " << foo.bar << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
Foo() called
Foo(int) called
foo.bar is 5
```

Why isn't the `foo.bar` value 6? `Foo()` is called but doesn't set `bar` to 1. Why?

Comment: `Foo();` creates an unnamed temporary object and immediately destroys it. What is it that you _expected_ to happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the following constructor, the line with `Foo()` does not delegate to the previous constructor. Instead, it creates a new temporary object of type `Foo`, unrelated to `*this`.

```
Foo(int b)
{
    bar = 0;
    Foo(); // NOTE: new temporary instead of delegation
    bar += b;
    cout << "Foo(int) called" << endl;
}
```

Constructor delegation works as follows:

```
Foo(int b)
    : Foo()
{
    bar += b;
    cout << "Foo(int) called" << endl;
}
```

However, this is only possible with C++11.

Comment: +1 for noting "only possible with C++11" --> http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133642/186397.

Answer (score 3):

you can't use constructor like ordinary functions. in your code calling Foo() creates a new object in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have this line in the constructor:

```
bar = 0;
```

You are trying to call the other constructor with `Foo()` call in the second constructor, but it just creates a temp `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to call a constructor from another constructor

See

[Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor)

Unless you're running C++11