# C++ Delegated Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use a delegated constructor and am trying to follow the format found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190051/member-initialization-while-using-delegated-constructor), however, I am still having issues.

My `player.h` file is this:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

#include <string>

class Player
{
public:
   Player(void);
   Player(std::string name, int score);
   ~Player();
protected:
   std::string name_;
   int score_;
};

#endif
```

My `player.cpp` file is this:

```
#include "player.h"
Player::Player(std::string name, int score)
{
   score_ = score;
   name_ = name;
}

Player::Player(void) : Player(NULL,0)
{

}
```

However, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
1>a:\projects\test\src\player.cpp(5): error C2614: 'Player' : illegal member initialization: 'Player' is not a base or member
```

What am I doing wrong? If it is relevant, I am using VS2012.

Comment: As far as I know (though I don't know much), vs2012 doesn't support delegated constructors.

Comment: You want to use delegating constructors but don't even know how to use ordinary initializer lists? I think you might benefit from backing up a bit...

Comment: @KerrekSB I was using initializer lists, but I thought they might be causing the issue so I got rid of them. I'm not sure why you're trying to discourage people who are learning the language from learning the different ways to call a constructor.

Comment: @Kyryx: OK, fair enough - but with initalizer lists, the second constructor would have been easy to write as `Player() : name_(), score_() { }`, so not having delegating constructors wouldn't have been a big issue...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If it is relevant, I am using VS2012.

It is, because Visual Studio *doesn't implement* this C++11 feature. Sorry. There are quite a lot of [C++11 features they don't implement](http://cpprocks.com/a-comparison-of-c11-language-support-in-vs2012-g-4-7-and-clang-3-1/).

Comment: Oh.. Well that would explain it. Thank you

Comment: Gratz on your gold [tag:c++11] badge. :) I thought I could beat you to it before you reached 200 answers, but meh.

Comment: I can't understand why Visual Studio doesn't implement this...
Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe delegating constructors were introduced in VS 2013 (VS12, _MSC_VER 1800).

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an answer to your question, but even though your compiler doesn't support delegating con­struc­tors, I want to address a few separate issues that your code would otherwise have suffered from:

1. Use initializer lists, not assignment.
2. When constructing heavy objects, pass by value and move.
3. You cannot initialize a `std::string` from a null pointer. If you want an empty string, pass an empty string.
4. You should only very rarely and in very exceptional cases have a destructor.

Putting it all together, we arrive at the following code:

```
class Player
{
public:
   Player(std::string name, int score)
   : name_(std::move(name))
   , score_(score)
   { }

   Player()
   : Player("", 0)
   { }

protected:
   std::string name_;
   int         score_;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, helpful feedback. Do you think you can explain point 2 though?

Comment: @Kyryx: The point is that you should be able to say both `Player(str, 1)`, which makes a copy, and `Player(std::string("Hello"), 2)`, which can *move* the resource without an additional allocation. Passing to the constructor by value and moving allows you to permit both cases with maximal efficiency.

Comment: Good catch there with the string object receiving 0.  On Mac OS X, `std::string str(0);` crashes immediately.