# Empty Constructors in C++:

Tags: c++, constructor

In my code I am doing the following, but I am not sure if I am "allowed" to or if it is a good designing technique. I need to create an empty constructor, but I also need a constructor that initializes the variables given the parameters. So I am doing the following:

This is the C.h file.

```
 class C
 {
   private:
    string A;
    double B;
   public:
   //empty constructor
   C();
   C(string, double);  
 }
```

And my C.cpp file:

```
//this is how I declare the empty constructor
 C::C()
  {

  }


  C::C(string a, double b)
  {
         A = a;
         B = b;
  }
```

Is the way I am declaring the empty constructor right or do I need to set A= NULL and B=0.0?

Comment: didn't you try to compile it?

Comment: It works, compiles and runs, of course, I am just asking whether this is "allowed" or if it is a bad design technique

Comment: If it compiles, then it is allowed. for this simple program you should not be thinking about design aspects.

Comment: both are good, some people hate default values, some hate additional constructor :) also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor

Comment: @Anil: 1) Just because something compiles does not mean it's good. `int* i = nullptr; *i = 5;` also compiles. 2) Never discourage someone from thinking about design.

Comment: @GManNickG when you are in desert you should be looking about water not gold, when come out of desert or when you have enough water you can look about gold. That is what I meant.

Comment: @Anil but it doesn't work as OP expects. `B` is not zero initialized. That is a very important deviation from the expected behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza he is not expecting that B should be zero, he is asking what should be done when an empty constructor is called. And the meaning of "allowed" is ambiguous here, who should allow? I am thinking about compiler allowing it, then the only check is that it  should compile. he is asking whether it is right or wrong, right or wrong is subjective(may be he is thinking about design aspect), then how did expected behavior has come into picture?

Comment: @Anil OP says "Is the way I am declaring the empty constructor right **or** do I need to set A= NULL and B=0.0?".

Comment: @juanchopanza will that mean he is expecting some behavior?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24661/discussion-between-anil-and-juanchopanza)

Comment: @juanchopanza what is the behavior he is expecting?

Comment: @Anil `B` to be set to `0` and `A` to be `NULL`. The latter makes no sense, but one can imagine an empty string is good enough. The former requires more than an empty constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza if he is expecting that behavior then how the question "do I need to set A= NULL and B=0.0?" become logical?

Comment: @Anil OP is asking if the empty constructor will do that or if he has to do it by hand. Seriously, it isn't that complicated.

Comment: @juanchopanza he is wording doesn't imply that unless you peep into his mind.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your empty constructor does not do what you want. The `double` data member will not be zero-initialized unless you do it yourself. The `std::string` will be initialized to an empty string. So the correct implementation of the default constructor would simply be

```
C::C() : B() {} // zero-initializes B
```

Concerning the other constructor, you should prefer the initialization list:

```
C::C(const string& a, double b) : A(a), B(b) {}
```

otherwise, what you are doing is an *assignment* to default constructed objects.

Answer (score 9):

In C++11 and later you can use the following to generate a default no-param constructor:

```
C() = default;
```

This is neater than C(){}.

This doesn't initialize members. In C++11 you can initialize members in the same line of declaration:

```
int m_member = 0; // this is a class member
```

Those 2 features avoids having to create your own no param constructor to default initialize members. So your class can look like this when applying those 2 features:

```
class C
{
private:
    string A;
    double B = 0;

public:
   C() = default;
   C(string, double);  
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is equivalent to the OP's code. It does not actually zero-initialise those members. Click on the link for more

Comment: I didn't mention zero initializing members. Updated my answer to make it explicit about this.

Comment: Great, better, but the first line is still wrong. Instead of tacking things on to the end you will have to edit the existing content too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you revise your voting?

Comment: Yes, indeed I can :)

Answer (score 5):

It is fine to do this and leave the constructor empty, but you should be aware that uninitialized fields have undefined value. `string` is a class and it's default constructor takes care of its initialization, but `double` is not initialized here (in your defualt constructor), and its value is undefined (it may be whatever value previously exists in the memory).

Answer (score 3):

A is `std::string`, you can't set it to `NULL` but can set to empty string and `std::string` has default constructor which initialize it to empty string by default.

```
C::C()
:B(0.0)
{
}
```

Maybe you need a constructor constructor with default parameter instead of two constuctors?

```
C(const string& a= "", double b= 0.0)
: A(a),
  B(b)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are the only person who can answer this question, because it depends **entirely** on your requirements for a default-constructed object. Since you haven't mentioned what your requirements are, it's not possible to give a definitive answer. Some people will guess that you should initialize `B` to 0, but that decision should be based on your design, not on various notions of "good" programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave it as is. You can do this because both `string` and `double` can be default constructed. Meaning that you can say `string foo;` and not get any errors.

Contrast this with what happens here:

```
class Bar{
    private:
        Bar(); //Explicitly private;
};
Bar b;
```

Here we get an error about no constructor `Bar::Bar()` being found.

As to whether it's a good idea: It's hard to say without knowing the situation this class will be used in. Perhaps it's perfectly sensible to have it be in a unconfigured position. But for many classes, such as a class representing a file for example, allowing a file object which  doesn't point to any file is obviously wrong.

Comment: But OP probably wants the `double` to be zero-initialized, which it isn't with the empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct and you can see it by compiling your code. Your default constructor will initialize the string and double by calling their default constructors.  If you define any constructor in your class it will hide the default constructor created by compiler for you.

You can improve your constructor code by writing it like this

```
C::C(string a, double b):A(a), b(b)
{
}
```

Comment: But the double's "initialization" will leave it with an unspecified value, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: AFAIK, double does not have a default constructor, and B will not be initialized at all.