# Different memory address in C++ constructors

Tags: constructor, g++

I have two constructors in C++, and one constructor calls the other one in order not to duplicate initialization logic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
    int y;
public: 
    A(int x)
    {
        cout << this << endl;
        this->x = x;
    }

    A()
    {
        cout << this << endl;
        A(20);
    }

    ...
};
```

What is interesting is A() calls A(int), but the this pointer points to different address. Why is this? Or is this g++ bug?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A* a = new A();
}

0x7fa8dbc009d0 <-- from A()
0x7fff67d660d0 <-- from A(int)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `A(20);` is constructing a different instance of A within that constructor, not invoking the other constructor on the same instance.

See [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor) for how to invoke another constructor from a constructor.

If you are using a compiler that supports C++11, I think you can achieve what you want with this definition of the `A()` constructor:

```
A(): A(20)
{
    cout << this << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`A(20);` is a statement which constructs a new instance of `A`, not a call to `A`'s constructor on `this`.

You can't call another constructor overload inside a given constructor in C++03. However, you can achieve the same effect by using placement new. Replace:

```
A(20);
```

in your code with:

```
new (this) A(20);
```