# Are there any consequences from using *this to initialise a class?

Tags: c++, initialization, this

In a small game I'm writing, I have a class `Weapon` with two constructors, one which takes in some parameters to produce a custom weapon, and one that grabs a default one (the `CHAIN_GUN`):

```
Weapon::Weapon (void) {
    // Standard weapon
    *this = getWeapon(CHAIN_GUN);
    return;
}
```

---

**Question**: Are there any negative consequences from using `*this` and `operator=` to initialise a class?

Comment: It's pretty common to see a copy constructor implemented in a similar way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Imagine that someone asked you to draw a painting... would you;
>
> - first draw your *default* (*1st*) (that familiar smilie face you like so much),
> - then draw what that someone asked for (*2nd*),
> - only to draw the same thing one more time, but on the canvas containing your *default*,
> - and then burn the *2nd* painting?
>
> This post will try to explain why this simile is relevant.

---

**WHY IS IT A BAD IDEA?**

I've never seen a *default-constructor* implemented with the use of the *assignment-operator*, and honestly it's not something that I'd recommend, nor support during a *code review*.

The major problem with such code is that we are, by definition, constructing **two** objects (instead of one) and calling a *member-function*, meaning that we construct all our members two times, and later having to copy/move initialize all members by calling the *assignment operator*.

It's unintuitive that upon requesting construction of **1** object, we construct **2** objects, only to later copy the values from the *2nd* to the *1st* and discard the *2nd*.

*Conclusion*: **Don't do it**.

( **Note**: In a case where `Weapon` has base-classes it will be even worse )

( **Note**: Another potential danger is that the factory function accidentially uses the default-constructor, resulting in an infinite recursion not caught during compilation, as noted by @[Ratchet Freat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731620/ratchet-freak) )

---

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

In your specific case you are far better off using a *default-argument* in your constructor, as in the below example.

```
class Weapon {
public:
  Weapon(WeaponType w_type = CHAIN_GUN);
  ...
}
```

```
Weapon w1;             // w_type = CHAIN_GUN
Weapon w2 (KNOWLEDGE); // the most powerful weapon
```

( **Note**: An alternative to the above would be to use a [*delegating constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308276/1090079), available in C++11 )

Comment: and there is the danger of the factory using the default constructor (now or later in an ignorant change) resulting in infinite recursion

Comment: It's usually good to put `explicit` in front of single-argument constructors to avoid implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 16):

Using the assignment operator to implement a constructor is rarely a good idea.  In your case, for example, you could just use a default parameter:

```
Weapon::Weapon(GunType g = CHAIN_GUN)
: // Initialize members based on g
{
}
```

In other cases, you might use a delegating constructor (with C++11 or later):

```
Weapon::Weapon(GunType g)
: // Initialize members based on g
{
}

Weapon::Weapon()
: Weapon(CHAIN_GUN) // Delegate to other constructor
{
}
```

Comment: Just note that delegating constructors requires C++11 or later.

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO; if your compiler doesn't support delegating constructors, then make a common function `construct_me(GunType g)` which you call from each constructor.

Answer (score 7):

One thing to keep in mind is that if `operator=` - or any function it calls - is `virtual`, the derived-class version ***won't*** be invoked.  This could result in uninitialised fields and later Undefined Behaviour, but it all depends on your data members.

More generally, your bases and data members are guaranteed to have been initialised if they have constructors or appear in the initialiser list (or with C++11 are assigned to in the class declaration) - so apart from the `virtual` issue above, `operator=` will often work without Undefined Behaviour.

If a base or member has been initialised before `operator=()` is invoked, then the initial value is overwritten before it's used anyway, the optimiser may or may not be able to remove the first initialisation.  For example:

```
std::string s_;
Q* p_;
int i_;

X(const X& rhs)
  : p_(nullptr)  // have to initialise as operator= will delete
{
    // s_ is default initialised then assigned - optimiser may help
    // i_ not initialised but if operator= sets without reading, all's good
    *this = rhs;
}
```

As you can see, it's a bit error prone, and even if you get it right someone coming along later to update `operator=` might not check for a constructor (ab)using it....

You could end up with infinite recursion leading to stack overflow if `getWeapon()` uses the Prototype or Flyweight Patterns and tries to copy-construct the `Weapon` it returns.

---

Taking a step back, there's the question of why `getWeapon(CHAIN_GUN);` exists in that form.  If we need a function that creates a weapon based on a weapon type, on the face of it a `Weapon(Weapon_Type);` constructor seems a reasonable option.  That said, there are rare but plentiful edge cases where `getWeapon` might return something other than a `Weapon` object that can never-the-less be assigned to a `Weapon`, or might be kept separate for build/deployment reasons....

Comment: `there are rare but plentiful edge cases` nice.

Comment: @Cthulhu: yeah - not my best wording - rare as in rarely encountered and plentiful was in reference to many different idioms/patterns/designs. :D

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined a non-copy `=` assignment operator that lets the `Weapon` change its type after construction, then implementing the constructor in terms of assignment works just fine, and is a good way to centralize your initialization code. But if a `Weapon` is not meant to change type after construction, then a non-copy `=` assignment operator does not make much sense to have, let alone use for initialization.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure yes.

You already created object inside your "getWeapon" function, and then you copying it, that may be long operation. So, at least you have to try move semantic.

But.
If inside "getWeapon" you call to constructor (and you do, somehow "getWeapon" have to create your class to return it to your copy operation), you create very unclear architecture, when one constructor calls function that calls another constructor.

I believe you have to separate your parameters initialization to private functions, that have to be called from your constructors the way you want to.

Comment: Hmm, I am sure that a "I believe" answer is not necessarily a good answer.

Comment: I mean "IMHO" or "I'm sure". If that is differ from "I'm sure", then it's my language problems, in my "head" if was "I'm sure" :-) 
I think anyone can make mistakes, and maybe there can be situation and code when such things can be useful. That is why I offered move semantic first. So, person asked for advice, and I gave advice from my experience. I'm not sure it is the best experience ever, that is why I added variant of "IMHO".