# Exc_bad_access with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, xcode6, exc-bad-access

I have been working in a project using matrices and graphs. The problem is when I compile it, the next line pops up:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffff5f3ffff8)

It appears in the next method; which is a constructor of my class:

```
GrafoMatriz::GrafoMatriz(){
    maxVerts = 1;
    GrafoMatriz(maxVerts);
}
```

```
typedef int * pint;

class GrafoMatriz {
    ...
    int maxVerts;
    int numVerts; 
    Vertice * verts; // there's another class Vertice
    int ** matAd; 

    GrafoMatriz();
    GrafoMatriz(int mx); 
    ...
}

GrafoMatriz::GrafoMatriz (int mx){
    maxVerts = mx;
    verts = new Vertice[mx]; 
    matAd = new pint[mx]; 
    numVerts = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mx; i++)
        matAd[i] = new int[mx];
}
```

I have been reading about possible problems and it could be something wrong about pointers:

> The pointer could have never been initialized.
>
> The pointer could have been accidentally written over because you overstepped the bounds of an array.
>
> The pointer could be part of an object that was casted incorrectly, and then written to.
>
> Any of the above could have corrupted a different pointer that now points at or near this pointer, and using that one corrupts this one (and so on).

I guess it's something about my pointer `pint`, but I am new to C++. So, I haven't been able to fix it. By the way0, I'm using Xcode 6.4 on an Intel Macbook Pro.

Comment: Calling a constructor within a constructor will not have the apparently expected effect. see this answer for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @kuroineko in the comments, you cannot call a constructor from another constructor in C++. If you use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (or a later standard) then you can use [delegating constructors](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_delegating_constructors?lang=en). Otherwise you might want to define an initialization function, for example, like this:

```
void GrafoMatriz::Initialize(int mx){
    maxVerts = mx;
    verts = new Vertice[mx];
    matAd = new pint[mx];
    numVerts = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mx; i++)
        matAd[i] = new int[mx];
}
```

Then you can call this initialization function from your different constructors:

```
GrafoMatriz::GrafoMatriz(){
    Initialize(1);
}

GrafoMatriz::GrafoMatriz (int mx){
    Initialize(mx);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the rest of the shown code should compile. I don't know if the code related to your variable `matAd` is correct, but at least it doesn't crash for me.