# Passing an integer as the argument of a constructor function

Tags: c++

I just want to prompt some integer from the user and pass it to the constructor function

Here's my class:

```
class queen {
 int N;
 int** queens;
 int *BFSq;
 int s;
 int front = 0;
 int rear = -1;
 int *found;
```

And here's my constructor:

```
public:
queen(){};
queen(int n)
{
    N=n;
    queens = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        queens[i] = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            queens[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
     BFSq = new int[n];
    found = new int[n];
}
```

And here is my `main()`function:

```
int main(){
int ent = 0;
cout<<"Please enter the size of your board\n";
cin>>ent;
queen(ent);
 }
```

I just want to pass `ent` value as `int n` argument to my constructor,but i think I'm not doing it right because I'm getting errors

**EDIT:** the error is "redefinition of 'ent' with a different type:'queen' vs 'int' "

Comment: What are the errors? Are those constructors inside the class definition? It not you need `queen::queen()` and `queen::queen(int n)` instead

Comment: We need all the code.  E.g. `queen.h`.

Comment: Please include more code so we can see how the class is constructed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that so it can be formatted properly

Comment: @Kevin i just added some code is there any point about my question which is not clear to you?

Comment: @Kevin `queen::queen(int n)` doesn't work

Comment: Because the constructors were defined in the class definition. As I said, you only need to qualify the class if the constructors are outside the class definition. I made that recommendation before you showed the full definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call constructor from constructor in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main, `queen(ent);`, rather than creating a temporary queen using the constructor taking an `int`, tries to create a queen object called `ent` using the default constructor. Since `ent` already exists as an `int` the compiler throws an error. The solution is to create the object like this: `queen q(ent);`

Comment: doesn't seems to work also `ent` in `queen(ent)` doesn't refer to an object and even the compiler knows it when you just type that function,it knows that it supposed to be an integer

Comment: What is the error you're having then? I'm stuck using an older version of g++ at the moment so my error might not be the same as yours. Edit it into your question

Comment: That's the same error as I had. Please replace `queen(ent);` with `queen q(ent);` and tell me if it fixes the issue