# Difference between calling a method within the body and calling it in a constructor-list

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class called Array2D with a copy-constructor `Array2D(const Array2D&)`. I had the problem that my program would stop whenever the copy-constructor was called. The constructor was:

```
Array2D(const Array2D& arr) {
    Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols); //Sets the variables cols and rows and
                                 //sets a pointer T* ptr = new T[rows*cols]
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr.ptr[i];
}
```

I moved the call for the other constructor to the contructor list:

```
Array2D(const Array2D& arr)
: Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr.ptr[i];
}
```

Could anyone tell me why the second version of the code works and the second one doesn't?

P.S.: This is the constructor that is called from the copy constructor.

```
Array2D(size_t r, size_t c)
: rows(r), cols(c), ptr(new T[r*c]) {}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c

Comment: I'll let you answer your own question by asking you:  what if in the first code, I wanted to create another Array2D inside of the constructor, completely separate and apart from `*this`?  How would I do that?  Ahh..do you see now what the first code is actually doing?

Comment: Looks like somebody is moving away from Java :)

Comment: @SergeyA You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
Array2D(const Array2D& arr) {
    Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols); //Sets the variables cols and rows and
                                 //sets a pointer T* ptr = new T[rows*cols]
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr.ptr[i];
}
```

`Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols);` is basically a non-op.  It creates a temporary `Array2d` and then it gets destroyed.  This means `ptr` is never initialized and using it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With

```
Array2D(const Array2D& arr)
: Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr.ptr[i];
}
```

You use a delegating constructor to initialize the member variables and then you set the array elements.

Comment: I didn't know that you could create an object without assigning it a name. Thank you!

Comment: @N.Pich It is perfectly legal.  It is one of the the ways you use `auto` like: `auto data = std::vector<int>(some_size);`.  Here we create a temporary vector and then it is with copied/moved/elided into `data`.

Comment: @N.Pich What would you have thought happened if say, you moved that `Array2D(arr.rows, arr.cols)` after the `for` loop?  That would have been legal also.  Doing that would have caused some suspicion that the line in question was not really being used to construct your current object.