# Initialize member variables with multiple constructor calls

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ABC {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    ABC(){
        cout << "Default constructor called!" << endl;
        ABC(2, 3);
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
    ABC(int i, int j){
        cout << "Parameterized constructor called with parameters "<< i << " " << j << "!" << endl;
        x = i;
        y = j;
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    ABC a;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following output:

> Default constructor called!
>   Parameterized constructor called with parameters 2 3!
>   2 3
>   -858993460 -858993460

**Shouldn't the member variables be initialized with values 2 and 3?**

Comment: `ABC(2, 3);` creates a local tempoary instance of `ABC`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So how should I make the changes on the same object?

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c).

Comment: @lapk That isn't the same. Being able to construct `ABC` with one argument might not be wanted.

Comment: @Ashish - If delegating constructors are not available, you have to do it the old way: `ABC() : x(2), y(3) { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ABC(2, 3);` doesn't call the constructor to initialize the members, it just create a temporary variable which will be destroyed immediately.

If you meant [delegating constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) you should:

```
ABC() : ABC(2, 3) {
    cout << "Default constructor called!" << endl;
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}
```

Note this is a C++11 feature. You can add a member function if you can't use C++11.

```
class ABC {
private:
    int x, y;
    init(int i, int j) {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }
public:
    ABC(){
        cout << "Default constructor called!" << endl;
        init(2, 3);
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
    ABC(int i, int j){
        cout << "Parameterized constructor called with parameters "<< i << " " << j << "!" << endl;
        init(i, j);
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a temporary variable in `ABC()` body. You can use this syntax to overcome this:

```
class ABC 
{
private:
   int x, y;
public:
   ABC() : ABC(2,3)
   {
       std::cout << "Default constructor called!" << std::endl;
   }
   ABC(int i, int j)
   {
       std::cout << "Parameterized constructor called with parameters "<< i << " " << j << "!" << std::endl;
       x = i;
       y = j;
       std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
   }
};
```

Comment: I can't compile this block of code on the IDE I'm using (Visual Studio 2010 Professional).
> Error 1 error C2614: 'ABC' : illegal member initialization: 'ABC' is not a base or member

Comment: @Ashish This is available with the current c++11 standard only. VS2010 is too old.