# Creating new object without passing parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, constructor

I'm reading **Data Structures and Algorithms Using C#** (Michael McMillan).

In **chapter 3 Page 43**, I found code snippet that take parameter in constructor but creating object without passing anything.

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: Usually, it is a good idea to post source code as text, not as image.

Comment: To answer your question: Probably there are several overloads of the constructor. E.g. one without parameters like `public CArray()` and one with `public CArray(int size)` and maybe others, too.

Comment: Do you try optional parameter with default value?

Comment: @UweKeim Got it, I'm Posting First Time.

Comment: It could be a typo

Comment: @UweKeim Image contains complete code. No Overload Method defined...

Comment: @ImranShams i'm not trying, I just saw this snippet in Course book & get confused.

Comment: I've found a PDF version through Google on [this URL](ftp://ftp.rau.am/_MAIN_/Books/Books%20CSharp%20New/Cambridge.University.Press.Data.Structures.and.Algorithms.Using.CSharp.Mar.2007.pdf). I've searched through all the document and found no other c'tor. Since your code is screenshot is missing a closing `}` I'm pretty sure that the whole class is _not_ printed in the book. The source code is available [here](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/cs/). There is no `CArray` at all in the full source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could a few possibilities:

- ***A typo***
- ***There is another overload***

  ```
  public CArray(int size)
  {
      // Implementation.
  }
  public CArray()
  {
      // Other implementation.
  }
  ```
- ***There could be a default value***

  ```
  public CArray(int size = 8)
  {
      // Implementation.
  }
  ```

---

Even though the code provided in the question will not compile 'as is' (without one of the 3 explanations - there is a way to create ***an uninitialized instance*** with no constructor call at all using `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices`:

```
class SomeType
{
    int mVariable;

    public SomeType(int size)
    {
        mVariable = size;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type someType = typeof(SomeType);
    SomeType instance = (SomeType)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(someType);
    // instance.mVariable = 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this method is slow and unsafe since you may use the `class` in a way its developer didn't mean you to and manually override the constructor, hence ***it should be used for serialization purposes only*** and not for general initialization.

Answer (score 2):

First of all yes it is possible, but in this context I don't think so.
You can create multiple constructors which would allow this situation like:

```
public CArray() {
   this(5); 
}
public CArray(int size){
   arr = new int[size]; 
   //other logic's must be here
}
```

To describe: The first Constructor is more or less the "default constructor" which will enter the other Constructor with the parameter size. You can also add some more Constructors.

Comment: yep i know there are many constructor possibility, writer should have mention other constructor too..

Comment: I hope you know it now. Please mark the best answer (in your opinion) as right and accept it.

Comment: This is not the syntax for [calling a constructor from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

For the code to be compiled `CArray` must have parameterless constructor;
the most probable syntax is

```
   public CArray()
     : this(0) {
   }
```

i.e. if `size` is not specified, let it be equal to `0`

Answer (score 1):

The default parameterless constructor is not available If you define a custom constructor with parameters in your class.

In that case if you want to keep the parameterless constructor you have to define it explicitly in your class.

So in your example, based on the class definition you provided, is not possible to create a new instance like this: `new CArray()`

Answer (score 1):

You must to have a Constructor with no parameter and there is some way:

- 1: Optional parameter
- 2: Multiple Override

---

**1: Optional parameter:**

```
public class CArray {
     private int[] arr;
     private int upper;
     private int numElements;

     //Constructor with default value parameter
     public CArray(int size = 0)
     {
         //Your logic must be here
     }
}
```

---

**2: Multiple Override**

```
public class CArray {
     private int[] arr;
     private int upper;
     private int numElements;

     //Constructor with zero parameter
     public CArray()
     {
         this = new CArray(0);
     }
     public CArray(int size)
     {
         //Your logic must be here
     }
}
```

---

So at end and after define your class, you can use in two type:

```
var MyArray1 = new CArray();
var MyArray2 = new CArray(10);
```