# Error: "className" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "className"

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an explicit constructor that calls the default constructor, but it says that i don't have one.

```
class Paddle{
private:

    int x, y;
    int startX, startY;

public:

    Paddle(){
        x = y = 0;
    }

    Paddle(int posX, int posY) : Paddle(){  // <-- the error is on ": Paddle()"
        startX = posX;
        startY = posY;
        x = posX;
        y = posY;
    }
};
```

What exactly causes this to happen, and how can i fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your compiler version and flags?

Comment: Have you enabled C++11 in your compiler args?

Comment: read this one this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c its only supported in c++11 up

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012. It should be working with c++11 code, as far as i know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct syntax, but *constructor delegation* is not supported until C++11.

Visual Studio 2012 does not purport to implement the C++11 standard. Constructor delegation is one of those things that is *doesn't* support.

Comment: That's... not an answer, really

Comment: I don't understand the reason why it wouldn't be considered to be an answer. The code is correct C++11, so the only thing it can be is the compiler.

Comment: Because the resolution is not self contained "Do check your compiler documentation." is not an answer, it's a comment at best.

Comment: The OP has helped me refine this answer. Hopefully it is better received now.

Comment: @StoryTeller, from your bio on this site: "I don't believe in answering questions completely. IMHO, one gains the most when one deduces as much of the answer on their own." :-P

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I try to walk the fine line of not giving too much, while not giving too little :)

Comment: @StoryTeller, Which, having looked at some of your excellent answers, you do with aplomb!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, i forgot to mention my compiler version.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you use visual studio 2012. Unfortunately it doesn't support delegating constructors. You can see a table of supported features by version at msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement) don't allow a constructor to call other constructors definition of the same class at the initialization level.

When you write `Paddle(int posX, int posY) : Paddle() ...` the compiler understands `Paddle` is a super class of `Paddle` or a member of `Paddle` which is not the case.
All what you need is a default parameters like this:

```
class Paddle{
private:

    int x, y;
    int startX, startY;

public:
    Paddle(int posX=0, int posY=0):x(posX),y(posY),startX(posX),startY(posY) {}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

this is allowed in C++11 see [Object construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement)