# Error: expression cannot be used as an function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function, delegating-constructor

I'm new to lambdas, I made my own binary heap class with custom comparator function.
It went well until I got a compilation error and I don't know how to fix.

I tried to change my line of code a bit, instead of

```
this(capacity, [](int a, int b){return a - b;});
```

I changed to this:

```
function<int(int, int)> cmp = [](int a, int b){return a - b;};
this(capacity, cmp);
```

I got the same result. How to deal with this error?

binary heap class:

```
class binaryheap
{
private:
    int *heap;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    function<int(int, int)> cmp;
    int parent(int i);
    int left_child(int i);
    int right_child(int i);
    void swap(int *a, int *b);
    void heapify(int i);
public:
    binaryheap(int capacity);
    binaryheap(int capacity, const function<int(int, int)>& cmp);
    ~binaryheap();
    bool empty();
    int heap_size() const;
    int get_root() const;
    int extract_root();
    void decrease_key(int i, int value);
    void insert_key(int key);
    void delete_key(int i);
};
```

The part of my code with a compilation error

```
binaryheap::binaryheap(int capacity)
{
    this(capacity, [](int a, int b){return a - b;});//binaryheap.cpp:51:58: error: expression cannot be used as a function
}

binaryheap::binaryheap(int capacity, const function<int(int, int)>& cmp)
{
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->heap = new int[capacity + 1];
    this->size = 0;
    this->cmp = cmp;
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah. `this` is a pointer to your object; it's not a function. What are you trying to do with `this( ... )`?

Comment: I learned from Java that this(...) will call a constructor of the object.

Comment: C++ is not Java.

Comment: Most of your code is unnecessary. Your error can be reduced to `struct foo { void bar() { this(); } };`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to use the delegating constructor feature; so

```
 binaryheap::binaryheap (int capacity)
     : binaryheap{capacity, [](int a, int b){return a - b;}}
  { }
```

or, as suggested by melpomene (thanks), you can delete this constructor and add a default value (`[](int a, int b){return a - b;}`) for the second argument in the other constructor.

Comment: but make sure you are using c++11 or later versions

Comment: Or just use a single constructor with a default argument.

Comment: @SaraTarek - the OP is using lambda functions and `std::function`, so is using C++11 or newer.

Comment: @melpomene - You're right; should be obvious but is better explicit it. Thanks.