# Is it possible to call default constructor from move constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a move constructor and need to initialize other back to it's original state, as implemented in the default constructor. Is this possible or do I need to duplicate the code?

```
class Class
{
  Class() { /* code to duplicate */ }
  Class(Class&& other) :
    mMember(other.mMember) {
    other.Class(); // code to duplicate?
  }
};
```

I know other.Class() is invalid here and I know that constructors can call each other with C++11 now.

Comment: What you seem to be wanting to do is to *swap* the default uninitialized state of `*this` with `other`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Won't that risk some kind of undefined behavior? And if it won't, is that really a good suggestion to make?

Comment: I'd rather write `Class(Class &&other) : mMember(std::exchange(other.mMember, {})) {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to reassign it. Since the object is already constructed, it would be a mistake to call the constructor again.

However, you can create an instance and call the assignement operator:

```
Class(Class&& other) noexcept : mMember(std::move(other.mMember)) {
    other = Class{};
}
```

Another way would be to default construct your class and swap values with the old one:

```
Class(Class&& other) noexcept {
    std::swap(mMember, other.mMember);
}
```

If you really need `other` to take the value it would from calling the default constructor, you can do this:

```
Class(Class&& other) noexcept : Class() {
    std::swap(mMember, other.mMember);
}
```

It will call the default constructor in the new object and then swap the values from the `other` object.

Comment: The move constructor should [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c) to the default constructor.

Comment: The ask was to restore `other` to the state of a default constructed object... (the delegation comment only applies to your `swap` suggestion).

Comment: @jxh, true, but I assume OP want's to do that so it's moved properly. The default constructed values may suffice. I will add a section in the answer.