# Call constructor with different argument types from another constructor in C++17

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class called Date:

```
class Date {
public:
    explicit Date(const int day = 1, const int month = 1, const int year = 0) {
        this->Construct(day, month, year);
    }

    explicit Date(const string &date_as_string) {
        int day, month, year;
        // parsing the string date_as_string
        this->Construct(day, month, year);
    }

private:
    void Construct(const int day, const int month, const int year) {
        // constructing the Date object
    }
};
```

Is there a way to call Date(int, int, int) directly from Date(string&), thus avoiding writing a separate function?

**UPD:**

Some clarification. My class should look like:

```
class Date {
public:
    explicit Date(const int day = 1, const int month = 1, const int year = 0) {
        // constructing the Date object
    }

    explicit Date(const string &date_as_string) {
        int day, month, year;
        // parsing the string date_as_string
        // call Date(day, month, year) to construct the Date object
    }

  // any other functions

private:
    // private fields
};
```

And the following code should compile:

```
Date date("some_string_containing_date");
Date date(1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c)

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-6-overlapping-and-delegating-constructors/

Comment: @NathanOliver Huh?! Delegating constructors anyone?

Comment: I don't think the dupe is appropriate because in this case the data needs some processing first. I think an example would help.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux *thus avoiding writing a separate function?* Using a delegating constructor would require writing a separate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define one constructor in terms of another. No, I don't think you can do it without some additional function.

A constructor which invokes another constructor of the same class is called a "[delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor)", and uses the same sort of syntax as a member initializer list, but using the class's own name instead of its base classes and members:

```
ClassName::ClassName(SomeParam1 p1, SomeParam2 p2)
    : ClassName(arg_expr1, arg_expr2, arg_expr3)
{ /* any other logic after the target constructor finishes */ }
```

But this case is a bit tricky because of the need for the intermediate object `date_as_struct`. Or with the updated question, just the need to do some parsing before entering another constructor. I'd solve this one by making an additional private constructor which takes the `Date_as_struct`:

```
class Date {
public:
    explicit Date(int day = 1, int month = 1, int year = 0); 
    explicit Date(const string &date_as_string);
    /* ... */
private:
    struct Date_as_struct {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };

    explicit Date(const Date_as_struct&);

    static Date_as_struct ParseStringContainingDate(const std::string&);
};
```

`Date_as_struct` and `ParseStringContainingDate` are declared here as private, since it sounds like nothing else will really use them.

Then for the string constructor, you just have

```
Date::Date(const std::string& date_as_string)
    : Date(ParseStringContainingDate(date_as_string))
{}
```

The `Date(const Date_as_struct&)` constructor can very easily delegate to `Date(int, int, int)` or vice versa, whichever is more natural for the actual member initialization.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! There is no function ParseStringContainingDate() and there is no struct Date_as_struct in my code. I introduced these objects for simplicity. In my code, Date(const string &date_as_string) performs parsing.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I have edited the code.

Comment: If that's the case, the string constructor can't make use of the 3-int constructor, since a delegating constructor always invokes its target constructor as the very first thing, and there is no other way to use a different constructor for the same object. It might be worth introducing `Date_as_string` and `ParseStringContainingDate` as shown here just to make the code reuse possible.

Comment: That is why I started the topic. I've seen these posts about delegation constructor but I had no idea how it should be used in this case. Thank you for your answer anyway!