# delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYcBE.png)

How do I declare a delegate constructor?

Please tell me how to declare a delegation constructor in a version other than C++11.

Comment: Please, don't include images of source code but paste the source code as text.

Comment: Switch to C++11? It's 2023.

Comment: What version of gcc do you use? Please, [edit] your question and add the output of `gcc --version`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c)

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: It is not "only in C++11", it is "C++11 or later". Before C++11 it just didn't exist.